# Apache Camel RouteBuilder in Spring doesn't launch configure()

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm working with Apache Camel to create route between dynamic endpoints. I was working with a Main which works but now I need to deploy the application on an Apache Tomcat server. The problem his that my camel-context doesn't found my route builder. Here is my applicationContext :

```
<bean id="myRoute" class="com.ittb.boa.jis.extractor.MyRouteBuilder">
    <constructor-arg name="src" ref="logsFileConnector" />
    <constructor-arg name="dest" ref="elasticSearchConnector" />
</bean>

<camelContext id="myCamel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="myRoute" />
</camelContext>
```

And I'm getting the following error :

```
    [         localhost-startStop-1] ContextLoader                  ERROR Context initialization failed
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.CamelException: Cannot find any routes with this RouteBuilder reference: RouteBuilderRef[myRoute]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1619)[camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:328)[camel-spring-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)[catalina.jar:8.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_45]
juil. 01, 2015 2:55:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.CamelException: Cannot find any routes with this RouteBuilder reference: RouteBuilderRef[myRoute]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1619)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:328)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.CamelException: Cannot find any routes with this RouteBuilder reference: RouteBuilderRef[myRoute]
    at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.installRoutes(AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.java:832)
    at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.setupRoutes(AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.java:352)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:326)
    ... 17 more
```

I've tried to debug it with an EndPoint on configure() in MyRouteBuilder and the error appears before the breakpoint..

Here is the method configure() which is quite heavy :

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
private ConnectorEndPoint src;
private ConnectorEndPoint dest;

int i = 0;
private String CRON_EXPRESSION_QUARTZ = CRONGenerator.generateCRONExpression("0/1", "9-17", "?", "*", "MON-FRI");

private MyProcessor processor = new MyProcessor();
RestConsumerFactory consumerFactory = new RestConsumerFactory() {
    public Consumer createConsumer(CamelContext camelContext, Processor processor, String verb, String basePath, String uriTemplate, String consumes, String produces, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
};

public MyRouteBuilder(ConnectorEndPoint src, ConnectorEndPoint dest) {
    this.src = src;
    this.dest = dest;
}

public void configure() {
    if (src instanceof ConnectorSQL){
        from("quartz2://foo?cron="+ CRON_EXPRESSION_QUARTZ)
        .to(src.getRouteFrom())
        .bean(processor, "conversionNumericAndDate")
        .bean(processor, "standardisation")
        .to(dest.getRouteTo());
    } else if (src instanceof ConnectorMongoDB){
        from("quartz2://foo?cron="+ CRON_EXPRESSION_QUARTZ)
        .to(src.getRouteFrom())
        .bean(processor, "convertDBObjectToString")
        //.bean(processor, "conversionNumericAndDate")
        .to(dest.getRouteTo());
    } else if (src instanceof ConnectorREST){
        from("quartz2://foo?cron="+ CRON_EXPRESSION_QUARTZ).to(src.getRouteFrom())
        //.bean(processor, "conversionNumericAndDate")
        //.bean(processor, "standardisation")
        .to(dest.getRouteTo());
    } else if (src instanceof ConnectorXMLFile){
        XmlJsonDataFormat xmlJsonFormat = new XmlJsonDataFormat();
        xmlJsonFormat.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        xmlJsonFormat.setForceTopLevelObject(true);
        xmlJsonFormat.setTrimSpaces(true);
        xmlJsonFormat.setSkipNamespaces(true);
        xmlJsonFormat.setRemoveNamespacePrefixes(true);         
        from("file:xml?scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron="+ CRON_EXPRESSION_QUARTZ)
        .marshal(xmlJsonFormat)
        .to(dest.getRouteTo());
    } else if (src instanceof ConnectorLogsFile){
        ArrayListAggregationStrategy aggregationStrategy = new ArrayListAggregationStrategy();
        from(src.getRouteFrom())
        .bean(processor, "lineFilter(${body}, " + src.getFieldToFilter() +", " + src.getFirstValue() +", " + src.getSecondValue() + ")")
        .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
        .filter().method(MyFilter.class, "isValidError")
        .bean(processor, "processLogsApplicationSource")
        .filter().method(MyFilter.class, "dateFilter(${body}, " + src.getFieldToFilter() +", " + src.getFirstValue() +", " + src.getSecondValue() + ")")
        .aggregate(body(), aggregationStrategy).completionInterval(1000)
        .to(dest.getRouteTo());
    } else {
        System.err.println("Erreur : Type de endpoint en entrée inconnu");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

So, it's like the camel context doesn't launch configure() method so the RouteBuilder is not created and not found by the context.. My web.xml is :

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.camel.component.servletlistener.SimpleCamelServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Several suggestions:

1. Check if the `RouteBuilder` bean is actually being created in the container.
2. Does your `MyRouteBuilder` extend `RouteBuilder` from camel?

Just for more clarification, please provide the full code for `MyRouteBuilder` and full stacktrace.

Comment: I've edit my post with the full MyRouteBuilder, it seems that it is created. It goes trough the constructor so src and dest are initalized, and yes it extends RouteBuilder.. For the Stacktrace, they is an other error but it's a repetition of the first

Comment: 1. I would still ask for the full stacktrace :)
2. Try to add `@Override` annotation to the method.

Comment: Edited ;) I've tried @Override but still have the error.. I've just see this in the tomcat logs : `juil. 01, 2015 3:05:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
juil. 01, 2015 3:05:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFOS: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext`

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from an error with a SimpleRegistry bean just before the RouteBuilder.

Comment: The simple registry is for java main, when using spring you must not use that, but let spring start its usual way, or use the main from camel-spring. And then the registry is a spring app context registry. See the various camel-spring examples etc.